# Setting a background drawabe for actionbar in android

Tags: android, image, background, android-actionbar

I need to set different background image for action bar for different fragments.
I am using the v4 support package. But I am getting a white background instead of the given image.

Below is the code I have used.

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.id.image));
```

and also

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
        BitmapDrawable actionBarBackground = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bMap);
        ActionBar bar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(actionBarBackground);
```

I have created this style and used it in the manifest for the activity

```
android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme"

 <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
 <item name="android:background">@drawable/image</item>
 </style>

 <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
 <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
 </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <!-- other activity and action bar styles here -->
    </style>

    <!-- style for the action bar backgrounds -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
```

In your manifest file:

```
 <activity android:name=".activity"
                  android:theme="@style/CustomActivityTheme"/>
```

Comment: I tried this.Still shows only a white background when i switch between the fragments

Comment: Are you using sherlock action bar or native holo?

Comment: Actually it have to display different backgroundimages for different fragments. So whatever is required for the first fragment i have specified in the theme in the manifest , but for the next fragments i have set it through the code, which is not working.And displays a white background.

Comment: @ Tarun I am using "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" not sherlock

Comment: `ActionBar bar = getActionBar();`
`bar.setBackgroundDrawable(actionBarBackground);` this should have worked.

Comment: have you tried this: `getActivity().getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image));` , you should use `R.drawable.image` instead of `R.id.image`